# NBA data only loads sometimes on google compute VM

Tags: javascript, java, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have an interesting issue where I tried to access the play-by-play data for the double-OT NBA game here: https://www.nba.com/games/20190110/OKCSAS#/pbp (click on the play-by-play link).

On both my windows and linux google compute engine VM's, using firefox or chrome, the play-by-play data is blank: 
[image]

Yet on some other games the play-by-play appears fine on the same google cloud VM computers: https://www.nba.com/games/20190112/DETLAC#/pbp (click on play-by-play)

[image]

**I can access either just fine from my local computer, but only some from any browser on either my windows or linux google compute VMs**

Can someone tell me why certain pages can't load on the google VM or what the difference between how these two pages load is?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll learn a lot by opening developer tools and looking at the JavaScript console when you click on that link.  I'm told that I don't have access.  You'll learn why it works on one device and not on others if you try it.

Comment: I've scoured the elements trying to figure it out, but it just doesn't seem to load for some reason.